# Finding properties of the sequence.

Tags: sequences-and-series, dirichlet-series

There is given a sequence $$\{a_{n}\}_{n>0}$$ of real numbers with following conditions:

1. $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}>0 ;$$
2. $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}\log n=0 ;$$
3. $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}(\log n)^{2}<0 .$$

What could be written about that sequence?
I know, that i must be specific, but i am looking for properties of sequence or partional sum such as

- asymptotic growth;
- distribution among real numbers;
- intervals of monotonicity;
- modality;
- some specific behaviour of subsequences;
- etc.

I will be grateful for any answer.

edit:
What if we use this substitution : $$\ a_{n}=\frac{c_{n}}{n^{x}}$$
Take a look at the sequence: $$\{c_{n}\}_{n>0}$$
How does this new defined sequence behave?
It determines Dirichlet series with real domain. I am curious when this series is somewhere concave and how it relate to its coefficients.

Comment: Interesting question. Do you have any thoughts yourself on what properties such a sequence should satisfy? It might be also worth thinking whether such a sequence even exists, and how you might go about constructing one if it does.

Comment: As an example, consider any converging (with positive terms) series $\sum_n b_n$ consider $(a_n)_n$ such that $a_{2n-1} = \frac{b_n}{\log(2n)}$, $a_{2n} = \frac{-b_n}{\log(2n+1)}$. If I'm not mistaken, it'll satisfy the assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

Sums impose only one constraint on a series and you have an infinite number of degrees of freedom, so there is not much that can be said.  To make the last sum converge we need the $a_n$ to go toward zero fast enough.  To get the last negative and the second zero we need many of the terms far out to be negative.  Only the first sum includes a contribution from $a_1$, so we just have to make $a_1$ large enough to make the first sum positive.